# Laptop won't recognize my drives as bootable after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

Previously, I have Windows 10 installed on my SSD, and my files are on multiple partitions of my HDD (files, programs,...)

Now I've decided to install Ubuntu and replace Windows.

I've wiped my SSD, created all the necessary partitions. See screenshots.

*SSD partition*

[image: ssd partitions]

*HDD partition*

[image: hdd partitions]

The problem is that my laptop doesn't recognize any of these drives as bootable.

Here are the BIOS screenshots.

[image: bios1]

[image: bios2]

[image: bios3]

Here's the boot-info before I did the grub boot-repair:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZRXCXfctbM/

After boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2mZqgBb7vz/

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I found this [Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot) solution for acer e15 but mine was acer v15, then i remembered my motherboard was replaced a year ago. 
So the solution worked.

Marked as solved.